# HTACCESS Not Picking Up The Path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using HTACCESS in my website but I'm facing a small problem with one of the files/links.

My link is `http://localhost/photos/view/1465574353`

My HTACCESS is:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$                index.php?category=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$       index.php?category=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$           view.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

When I follow the link I am not redirected anywhere at all, yet when I follow `http://localhost/photos/view.php?id=1465574353` I am shown the page.

Anyone know the reason why this may be?

** If I change it to

```
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$          view.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]` and visit my page at `localhost/photos/view/1465574353/title
```

I am shown the correct page!

FYI: I'm using the same format for my other section, which looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$                    index.php?section=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$           index.php?section=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^read/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$      read.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think you have to write `RewriteRule ^photos/view/([0-9]+)/?$           view.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]` instead of just view at the beginning

Comment: What is the location of your htaccess?

Comment: @starkeen - It's in the same folder as `index` and `view`

Comment: @instead - I don't think so, otherwise the `read` file wouldn't open up in my features folder!!!

Comment: @FootBlogger You mean `photos/` directory exists? Also, does the server config has `AllowOverride All` directive?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - The directory `photos/` exists, and I'm using a similar **working** code in the `features/` directory. If I go to http://localhost/photos/view.php?id=1465574353 I see the correct page, but visiting `http://localhost/photos/view/1465574353` throws me back to the `index` page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://localhost/photos/view/1465574353 is already matched by

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

- view - `([\w-]+)`
- 1465574353 - `([0-9]+)`

and therefore not handled by the final `RewriteRule`.

If you want it handled by the more specific (`view`) rule, you must swap the last two, because the rules are tried in order.

```
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)/?$ view.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&currentpage=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```